# Seagate serial ata disc drive - Data recovery

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery, sata

I have a Seagate Serial ATA Disc Drive (SATA) from my old Samsung laptop running Windows 7(internal drive). The computer had a faulty power Supply and would shut down randomly.
I would like to recover my data from this drive(very very important)
I tried using a Bridge but the drive was not detected, and I put it in my laptop and it wasn't detected either.
Is there any way to recover the data from this drive
Thanks

Comment: Without powering up the disk drive, do you remember if it made any unusual noises, such as clicking?

Comment: Contact a data recovery company. It will be expensive.

Comment: It did not make any clicking noises or anything but it was in my samsung laptop and it booted fine an i could see all of my data then all of a sudden the power supply failed and then the laptop would get stuck on the boot screen and when i took it out i tried  using an ata/atapi bridge but it wasnt detected. is there any way to do it with paying a company to recover the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you remembered clicking noises as described by Andrew Morton above, do not use the drive and contact a recovery company directly. If not do the following:

I don't know what type of connection "Bridge" should mean. Use a docking station to connect that drive to another computer to see if it appears (Windows: Disc Management, in linux use "lsblk"). External drive cases without power supply are not reliable due to high start-up currents exceeding specifications.
Stop using the drive if you notice any type of cyclical sound series or "clicking".
If the drive does not appear you need a data recovery company.